# Is it possible to inject sass/css updates for angular 2 components with browser-sync?

Tags: angular, browser-sync

I have browser-sync and I am able to dynamically inject and modify the CSS in my stylesheets that are hosted in the root of my application and not directly maintained by angular. This does not require a reload.

However, all of my angular styleUrls do not update if I make changes, unless I do a manual reload.

I notice Angular embeds the styles in the `<head>` element and so this is probably why it's not actually reloading.

Is there any way around this using browser-sync or any other techniques?

Comment: A workaround is to move all the styles into header

Comment: That's probably not possible because Angular has to calculate and apply the scope of the css injected with `styles` / `styleUrls` along with attaching them to `<head>`. Unless it's possible to trigger Angular to do so, or immitate Angular on your own. Anyway, you can configure `browserSync` to reload the app on css change anytime.

Comment: I'll wait until there are some answers specific to browser-sync... but my solution has been to switch my build process from gulp&browser-sync to webpack with webpack-dev-server and it's Hot Module Reloading. Once you get it set up, it's pretty neat, and does exactly what I'm looking for. It lets you inject not only css without refreshing the site, but also html and javascript which is very cool.

Answer (score 2):

If you create your app using the **Angular CLI** all these little issues are taken care of in advance, like [css preprocessors](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#css-preprocessor-integration) and the build/dev process. Once you are serving the app and  you modify anything (typescript/sass/scss) it gets reloaded and injected again for  you, give it a try!

Comment: @twilliams can you mark it as the correct answer please? ^_^